# BSNL 3G Data Card is installed in Ubuntu 12.04, but not opening

Tags: 12.04

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed in my laptop.

BSNL 3G Data Card software installed, but not opening.

What are the possible problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with MTNL 3G Jadoo data card (Teracom LW272) and resolved it as described here:
[Using "MTNL 3G Jadoo" data card on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/513886/using-mtnl-3g-jadoo-data-card-on-ubuntu).
Might help you too.