# Using "MTNL 3G Jadoo" data card on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, 3g

I am trying to use "MTNL 3G Jadoo" data card (Teracom LW272) with Ubuntu 12.04. On connecting, it gets mounted as a drive containing the client installation `.deb` file. I opened the `.deb` file in Ubuntu Software Center and installed it. I searched for "MTNL" in Ubuntu search and found "MTNL 3G Modem" application. But it won't run. I found it is installed in `/opt/MTNL-3GModem`. I tried running it unsuccessfully from the terminal with

```
sudo /opt/MTNL-3GModem/ModemClient
```

Any idea how to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i got it working on **12.04**:

I checked for any missing dependencies with `ldd /opt/MTNL-3GModem/ModemClient` and found **libudev0:i386** to be missing. So the application is 32-bit and i have 64-bit Ubuntu. I also found that [libudev0:i386 is no longer included with Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326940/cannot-install-vmware-view-client-on-13-04-amd64). I tried installing it with `apt-get` but got some errors. I finally downloaded it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libudev0) and installed it with Ubuntu Software Center. Then i started the MTNL application with `sudo /opt/MTNL-3GModem/ModemClient` and... success! Note that the application needs to be run with `sudo`.

UPDATE for **14.04**:
On upgrading to 14.04, the MTNL application failed to connect (on clicking the 'Connect' button). I found that it was using the `gksudo` command in its shell scripts, which is [not available since 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290810/how-to-add-gksudo-or-what-to-use-instead-in-ubuntu-13-04). So I replaced `gksudo` with `sudo` in two files in `/opt/MTNL-3GModem`: `connectnet.sh` and `deconnectnet.sh`. And that fixed the issue.